# find gamma from complex form?

Tags: complex

In $$e^{j\pi/\gamma x}=c$$ if $x$ and $c$ are known, how to find $\gamma$ since if we break to sine and cosine term the problem becomes more complicated. This is a complex value and $j$ indicates complex value.

Comment: Apply logarithm?

Comment: Which one of $c$, $x$, and/or $\gamma$ are  real and which ones are complex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `a concerned citizen` says:

```
import numpy as np
x = 0.1278147
c = 5.42958205

gamma = 1j*np.pi*x/np.log(c)
print(gamma)
```

yields

> 0.23733713769810083j